# How can I format a list inside a numbered list nicely

Tags: support, markdown, design

I posted on meta.stats a question with a bullet list in a numbered list. See the excerpt below (as most of you can't see that question yet).

As you can see it looks currently horrible. Is there a way to have this kind of structure in the formatting, but then that it looks nice?

---

1. Are questions about [subject] on or off topic?

   - R and Programming questions
   - Visualization questions
   - Machine Learning and Speech Recognition questions
2. What should our FAQ contain?

   - No topics yet
3. How should we tag questions about {subject}?

   - Tag rename requests

---

Markdown source:

```
1. Are questions about [subject] on or off topic?
  - R and Programming questions  
  - Visualization questions
  - Machine Learning and Speech Recognition questions  


2. What should our FAQ contain?
  - No topics yet  


3. How should we tag questions about {subject}?
  - Tag rename requests
```

---

Screenshot Chrome Linux:

[image: screenshot]

---

Disclaimer: This is all under the assumption that this formatting also not renders nice in other browsers besides Chrome under Linux.

The real question where this is about is [this one](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119/the-7-essential-meta-questions)

Comment: While I can't say that it looks nice here on IE8 on XP (there's a linebreak before each bullet sequence but not after them), a screenshot of how horrid it looks on Chrome/Linux might help illustrate.

Comment: @Grace That sounds like exactly the same... Let's see or I can fix a screenshot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

1. Are questions about [subject] on or off topic?

   - R and Programming questions
   - Visualization questions
   - Machine Learning and Speech Recognition questions
2. What should our FAQ contain?

   - No topics yet
3. How should we tag questions about {subject}?

   - Tag rename requests

Source:

```
1. Are questions about [subject] on or off topic?
  - R and Programming questions  
  - Visualization questions
  - Machine Learning and Speech Recognition questions  <p>
2. What should our FAQ contain?
  - No topics yet <p>
3. How should we tag questions about {subject}?
  - Tag rename requests <p>
```

or, with less haning paragraph tags:

```
1. Are questions about [subject] on or off topic?
  - R and Programming questions  
  - Visualization questions
  - Machine Learning and Speech Recognition questions  // note the two spaces
<br />
2. What should our FAQ contain?
  - No topics yet  // note the two spaces
<br />
3. How should we tag questions about {subject}?
  - Tag rename requests  // note the two spaces
<br />
```

Comment: O yes, this is already much better. Strange, I thought I tried it. Still I would like an empty line before every numbered item. Any idea if that is possible?

Comment: @Peter: Add a `<br/>`.

Comment: @badp, the br didn't work.  But adding some `<p>` tags seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @Peter, check out my edit

Comment: Ok, got it. The - line should end on 2 spaces and on the next line a <br/>. That makes formatting looks nice :)

Comment: @Justin, @Peter -- sorry, you are correct. _Two `<br/>`, not one_ are required :(

Comment: @badp, or make sure there are two spaces at the end of the line right before the `<br />`.  Either way, it's not easy to do.